# charset problem on strtolower()

Tags: php, string, character-encoding

i'm working on a polish website. I design mysql tables and columns as utf8_general_ci and add

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`

`<?php
uery = mysql_query("select * from messages order by id desc limit 1");`
`$array = mysql_fetch_array($query);`
`$string= $array["message"];`
`$string = strtolower($string);`
`echo "<br>$string"; 
?>`

result is something like `"prof. dr hab. in�. boles�aw pochopie�"`

so two question,
1- what is the problem why result is with unknown char? how can i fix it?
2-Is utf-8 and utf8_general_ci good for a polish website?

Comment: Make sure your database fields have the correct encoding, too.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [mb_strtolower](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php) for multibyte strings (this applies to many other string functions of php too, see [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php)).

Or you could request it directly from the database:

```
SELECT LOWER(message) FROM messages ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 1
```

EDIT: As for the encoding: `utf8_polish_ci` and `utf8_general_ci` are both ok.

Comment: yeah that's working but if multibyte extension is not enable what can i do?

Comment: @ocanal, I'd strongly suggest enabling it you're creating a UTF-8 based website. The other option is to get it converted by the database server, as I've already mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mb_strtolower()`, which doesn't treat one byte as one character.

If not available on your platform, you need to create it.

[Have a look at Kohana 3's `utf8::strotolower` helper](https://github.com/kohana/core/blob/3.1%2Fmaster/classes/kohana/utf8.php#L312).

Answer (score 0):

Use `utf8_polish_ci` and let MySQL do the sorting.